# Parsing JSON with Kotlin JS 'fun <T> parse(text: String): T`?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop, kotlin-js-interop

How can I use

`fun <T> parse(text: String): T`

to parse JSON in Kotlin JS?

e.g. how can I parse this JSON string?

```
{
"couchdb": "Welcome",
"version": "2.0.0",
"vendor": {
    "name": "The Apache Software Foundation"
}
}
```

Comment: You have a method definition there. But where is that coming from? Some library? It is really not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: @GhostCat stdlib : [parse - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-j-s-o-n/parse.html)

Comment: Interesting. But I am not too much into kotlin ;-(

Comment: @GhostCat kotlin JS is good but a bit buggy still, but overall I'm pleased

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with the parsed JSON. The easiest way would be

```
val jsonAny = JSON.parse<Any>(text);
```

Or you could parse it as a Json, which would allow you to access the properties:

```
val json = JSON.parse<Json>(text);
println(json["version"]);
```

Or - if you want to use the strict typing of kotlin - you may want to define a class that represents the structure and use its properties:

```
data class CouchDB(val version:String)

val jsonCouchDb = JSON.parse<CouchDB>(text);
println(jsonCouchDb.version)
```

After all, it will always be the same JS object returned by the javascript JSON.parse() method, Kotlin just introduces types here.

Comment: `JSON.parse<Map<String,Any>>` won't work. You rather should use [Json](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-json/index.html) class or declare `external interface`

Comment: What dependency would be used for this?